# ServerVersion = 'cmd.Connection.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I noticed that some others also have had the same issue but couldn't able to find a solution. My ASP.NET application was working perfectly and suddenly experienced this. It's not throwing any exceptions but the stored procedures become not returning values as previous. When I debug the program noticed that there is a problem with my `SqlCommand`.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["UserID"]));
DataTable dtuser = db.GetDataTable(cmd, "sp_GetUserbyUserId");
```

I added a watch and had a look on `cmd`. `Connection`'s `ServerVersion` property showing above message and the `Message` property saying `"Invalid operation. The connection is closed."`. I'm thinking my SPs are not functioning because of this. What would be the issue here? 
Recently what I did change in the web.config is just adding new field under `<appSettings/>`

**Edit**
Below is my `DBHandler` class method which is called by above `db` instance.

```
public class DBHandler
{
    private string connectionString = "";
    public DBHandler()
    {    
        connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConString"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTable(SqlCommand sqlcmdWithParameters, string CommandText)
        {
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmdWithParameters);

            using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlcmdWithParameters.Connection = sqlcon;
                sqlcmdWithParameters.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcmdWithParameters.CommandText = CommandText;
                try
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sqlda.Fill(ds, "Table");
                    dtReturn = ds.Tables["Table"];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                   //Handling Exceptions
                }
            }
            return dtReturn;
        }
}
```

My connection string in the Web.config is as follows

```
<connectionStrings>    
    <add name="myConString" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.x.x;Initial Catalog=myDB;User ID=myId;Password = myPWD" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: You need to post more code. How do you open/close your connection?

Comment: Hi @Szymon, I have added more codes there.Would it be help you to give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error.  On my machine while I had Visual Studio 2013 Open, I uninstalled and re-installed my Oracle Data provider.

After Oracle was re-installed I ran my otherwise working asp.net application and started getting this error when trying to, not create, but open a Database connection.

After closing visual Studio and reopening it, the error went away.  Perhaps something about my "ServerVersion" was invalidated and then reset when I reopened Visual Studio.